# Preserving Vuex State on page redirect

Tags: vue.js, redirect, vuex, zuora

I'm implementing a cart and currently using [Zuora's Direct Post](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/Zuora_Central/Billing_and_Payments/LA_Hosted_Payment_Pages/B_Payment_Pages_2.0/P_Implement_Direct_POST_for_Payment_Methods).

Basically it's a form submit to Zuora and upon success Zuora will redirect back to my site. They allow for 5 `field_passthroughs` which are just query string parameters in the url.

I have the flow working as such:

1. User enters in their Card Information
2. On Submit, information is submitted to Zuora
3. On Success, Zuora redirects back to my site, which lands on an intermediate processing page
4. Zuora sticks a few fields on the redirectURL such as `paymentMethodId`, which I use to place the order on the processing page.

I want to optimize it now so that instead of landing on the intermediate processing page, it'll just land back on the user's cart with the input fields still populated.

In order to achieve this without refetching fields like name/email from my backend, Is there a way I can pass it on the redirectUrl? Would it be safe to serialize my Vuex state into a string and encode it? Then when it lands back on my cart from the redirect, I decode and deserialize and repopulate the form?

Comment: @Yom S. thanks for formatting my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some of that information back automatically.

Any of the fields in the HOP page configuration in Zuora where the "Returned in Response" checkbox are checked will return as querystring parameters. Email, phone, and address fields can be returned this way.

Unfortunately (Cardholder) Name is not one that can be checked. That would have to be passed back through one of the field_passthroughs. I would say yes about passing it that way as it would be using https and querystring values are already encrypted.

I am not an expert on security and some fields like CC numbers should never be passed ths way.